# Angular http Get API string params for mat table

Tags: angular

I have an on click event. Which routes to a new component B. As part of component B it would create a mat table to fetch data, this table invoke a API service based on the click button. But i could not get any information back .. since i am passing APP[Object object] to the API instead of TOM. Below are my components and service code. Can someone help to resolve this please.

My params should at end of the URL as APP=TOM or APP=CAT. My Base URL is still

**Click event component.ts:**

```
    export class AppCardsComponent  {
 public app:String;  
  constructor(private route: Router) { }
  onCardClick(app:string) {
    this.app = app;
    this.route.navigateByUrl('/app');}
```

**routed component and table calling the get api component.**

```
export class ServerDataComponent implements OnInit {
  [x: string]: any;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['Environment', 'App_server', 'App_user', 'App_password', 'DB_Server','DB_user','DB_password','URL'];
  serversource;
  server;
  servers: Server[];

  constructor(private Serverdata:serverdata,public dialog: MatDialog){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.Serverdata.getservers("")
    .subscribe((servers: Server[]) => {
      this.servers = servers;
      console.log(this.servers);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.servers));

     this.serversource = new MatTableDataSource(servers);
    });
```

**Service.api:**

```
export class serverdata {

  baseURL="https://xxxxxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/Test/application?App="
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  getservers(app) {
      let params = new HttpParams().set('APP',app)
      console.log(params.toString());
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL + {params});
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is up to date? Here `this.Serverdata.getservers("")` you are passing an empty string to the service.

Comment: @Guillaume .. yes,this is what i am trying .. but could not go ahead..can you help me out.. I am not so good at angular.. just a begineer.

Comment: do you want pass "app" from component A to component B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass params from component A to B then you need to pass while routing from A to B & component B should be received that passed Param values.

```
 export class AppCardsComponent  {
 public app:String;  
  constructor(private route: Router) { }
  onCardClick(app:string) {
        this.app = app;
     this._route.navigate(['/app' + app]);
}
```

here  `this._route.navigate(['/app' + app]);` app is router parameters send from compoent A to B.
now component B shoud be receive whahtever parameter sent by A.using

```
ngOnInit() {
    // get URL parameters
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.values= params.app; // --> Name must match wanted parameter
    });
}
```

then you can pass received params to your method.

```
    export class ServerDataComponent implements OnInit {
      [x: string]: any;
      displayedColumns: string[] = ['Environment', 'App_server', 'App_user', 'App_password', 'DB_Server','DB_user','DB_password','URL'];
      serversource;
      server;
      servers: Server[];
     private values:any;

      constructor(private Serverdata:serverdata,public dialog: MatDialog){}

      ngOnInit() {
       this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
          this.values= params.app; // --> Name must match wanted parameter
        });
        this.getData();
       }

getData(){
 this.Serverdata.getservers(this.values)
        .subscribe((servers: Server[]) => {
          this.servers = servers;
          console.log(this.servers);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(this.servers));

         this.serversource = new MatTableDataSource(servers);
        });
}
}
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, I tried with the answer you help.. Data has been sent to route (ServerDataComponent) from AppCardsComponent. But when ServerDataComponent starts picking it up.. i am getting an '''error with core ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'appTOM'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'appTOM'''

Comment: update your app-routing.module.ts file with {path:'/app/:app',component:ServerDataComponent }

Comment: Without using http params, i was able to achieve it.. just by passing the variable to via route and send to service. thank you for helping @Sarjerao

Answer (score 1):

Add parameters for the request like:

```
const params = new HttpParams()
.set('APP', app);

return this.httpClient.get(this.baseURL,{params});
```

You are currently concatenating params object to URL string which will be why you are passing APP[Object object].

Also your url should not now have ‘?app=‘ as the params will be added as above.

But as noted in the comments, you are sending empty string for function argument:

```
this.Serverdata.getservers("")
```

To have the value available for the parameter, you can declare the ‘add’ variable  (public app:String) in your Serverdata service instead then inject the service into click handler component constructor also so you can set it like:

```
this.Serverdata.add = add;
```

It can then be read at service http call like this.app.

Or as noted in other answer, app value could be sent with route.